# How to make table view load all data at once and not change said data while scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm making a simple table view app to display and play all the iOS System sounds.

I have all of the sounds and ID's in a a dictionary(I now realize this was a bad way to do this) in the form of [ID(Int):Name(String)], the problem is that when I load my view it loads well, but if I scroll down the cells originally on top change. Same when scrolling from the bottom to the top.

For example, the view loads in and I can click and hear the various sounds from any of the cells I click on. Lets say the first cell is "SMS-Sound1" and the seconds is "SMS-Sound2". Now when I scroll down to where those cells are out of view and then scroll back to the the top they are named something different(Still from my data dictionary).

How would I fix this problem so that it loads the tableview and then the tableview data doesn't change?

Edit: I thought the problem could be in the fact that the for in loop was executed around 300,000 times but thats not the case, made an array of the IDS so it was only executed around 1000 times total and the problem persists

My Code:

Cell set up

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("soundCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let button = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel //UILabel in "SoundCell"
        for i: Int in 999..<4100 {
            //Lowest id sound is 1000, highest is 4095
            if (sounds[i] != nil) && loadedSoundStrings.contains(sounds[i]!) == false {
                button.text = sounds[i]
                loadedSoundStrings.append(sounds[i]!)
                cell.tag = i
                break
            }
        }

        return cell
    }
```

Rows/sections

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return sounds.count
    }
```

Variables:

```
let sounds =
        [   1000:"new-mail.caf",
            1001:"mail-sent.caf",
            1002:"Voicemail.caf",
            1003:"ReceivedMessage.caf",
            1004:"SentMessag.caf",
            1005:"alarm.caf",
            1006:"low-power.caf",
            1007:"sms-received1.caf",
            1008:"sms-received2.caf",
            1009:"sms-received3.caf",
            1010:"sms-received4.caf",
            1011:"-(SMSReceived_Vibrate)",
            1012:"sms-received1.caf",
            1013:"sms-received5.caf",
            1014:"sms-received6.caf",
            1015:"Voicemail.caf",
            1016:"tweet_sent.caf",
            1020:"Anticipate.caf",
            1021:"Bloom.caf",
            1022:"Calypso.caf",
            1023:"Choo_Choo.caf",
            1024:"Descent.caf",
            1025:"Fanfare.caf",
            1026:"Ladder.caf",
            1027:"Minuet.caf",
            1028:"News_Flash.caf",
            1029:"Noir.caf",
            1030:"Sherwood_Forest.caf",
            1031:"Spell.caf",
            1032:"Suspense.caf",
            1033:"Telegraph.caf",
            1034:"Tiptoes.caf",
            1035:"Typewriters.caf",
            1036:"Update.caf",
            1050:"ussd.caf",
            1051:"SIMToolkitCallDropped.caf",
            1052:"SIMToolkitGeneralBeep.caf",
            1053:"SIMToolkitNegativeACK.caf",
            1054:"SIMToolkitPositiveACK.caf",
            1055:"SIMToolkitSMS.caf",
            1057:"Tink.caf",
            1070:"ct-busy.caf",
            1071:"ct-congestion.caf",
            1072:"ct-path-ack.caf",
            1073:"ct-error.caf",
            1074:"ct-call-waiting.caf",
            1075:"ct-keytone2.caf",
            1100:"lock.caf",
            1101:"unlock.caf",
            1102:"-(FailedUnlock)",
            1103:"Tink.caf",
            1104:"Tock.caf",
            1105:"Tock.caf",
            1106:"beep-beep.caf",
            1107:"RingerChanged.caf",
            1108:"photoShutter.caf",
            1109:"shake.caf",
            1110:"jbl_begin.caf",
            1111:"jbl_confirm.caf",
            1112:"jbl_cancel.caf",
            1113:"begin_record.caf",
            1114:"end_record.caf",
            1115:"jbl_ambiguous.caf",
            1116:"jbl_no_match.caf",
            1117:"begin_video_record.caf",
            1118:"end_video_record.caf",
            1150:"vc~invitation-accepted.caf",
            1151:"vc~ringing.caf",
            1152:"vc~ended.caf",
            1153:"ct-call-waiting.caf",
            1154:"vc~ringing.caf",
            1200:"dtmf-0.caf",
            1201:"dtmf-1.caf",
            1202:"dtmf-2.caf",
            1203:"dtmf-3.caf",
            1204:"dtmf-4.caf",
            1205:"dtmf-5.caf",
            1206:"dtmf-6.caf",
            1207:"dtmf-7.caf",
            1208:"dtmf-8.caf",
            1209:"dtmf-9.caf",
            1210:"dtmf-star.caf",
            1211:"dtmf-pound.caf",
            1254:"long_low_short_high.caf",
            1255:"short_double_high.caf",
            1256:"short_low_high.caf",
            1257:"short_double_low.caf",
            1258:"short_double_low.caf",
            1259:"middle_9_short_double_low.caf",
            1300:"Voicemail.caf",
            1301:"ReceivedMessage.caf",
            1302:"new-mail.caf",
            1303:"mail-sent.caf",
            1304:"alarm.caf",
            1305:"lock.caf",
            1306:"Tock.caf",
            1307:"sms-received1.caf",
            1308:"sms-received2.caf",
            1309:"sms-received3.caf",
            1310:"sms-received4.caf",
            1311:"-(SMSReceived_Vibrate)",
            1312:"sms-received1.caf",
            1313:"sms-received5.caf",
            1314:"sms-received6.caf",
            1315:"Voicemail.caf",
            1320:"Anticipate.caf",
            1321:"Bloom.caf",
            1322:"Calypso.caf",
            1323:"Choo_Choo.caf",
            1324:"Descent.caf",
            1325:"Fanfare.caf",
            1326:"Ladder.caf",
            1327:"Minuet.caf",
            1328:"News_Flash.caf",
            1329:"Noir.caf",
            1330:"Sherwood_Forest.caf",
            1331:"Spell.caf",
            1332:"Suspense.caf",
            1333:"Telegraph.caf",
            1334:"Tiptoes.caf",
            1335:"Typewriters.caf",
            1336:"Update.caf",
            1350:"-(RingerVibeChanged)",
            1351:"-(SilentVibeChanged)",
            4095:"-(Vibrate)"]

var loadedSoundStrings = [String]()
```

Comment: The problem is simply that your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` takes no account whatever of what row this _is_. That's insane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are instantiating all of the sounds for every single row when you actually want to only instantiate the sound for the rows that are loaded. To fix your order issue change your
     `cellForRowAtIdexPath`

to this:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("soundCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
  let button = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel //UILabel in "SoundCell"
  button.text = sounds[i]
  cell.tag = indexPath.row
  return cell
}
```

This gives you 1 sound per cell since you have NumberOfRowsInSection set to sounds.count Cell for row will be called for every sound you have.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I think it would have been better for me overall to use something other than a dictionary for this..

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, you're going about it the wrong way. You have a dictionary of sounds that you load once. The `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function should be returning one tableViewCell with details for the one sound.

`UITableView` automatically discards cells that are off screen to conserve memory, and will reuse them for newly visible cells. That's why you call `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. Therefore you should just be doing:

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("soundCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let button = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel //UILabel in "SoundCell"
        //Lowest id sound is 1000, highest is 4095
        let i = indexPath.row + 1000
        button.text = sounds[i]
        cell.tag = i
        return cell
    }
```

Since you are hardcoding the sound number range I have done the same.

Answer (score 0):

A table view works best with an array, as an array has a defined order and you can quickly access a given element; a for loop in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is seldom a good thing.

You have a couple of issues, however, as your sounds identifiers don't start from 0, you can't use the identifier as a direct index into the array, but also the identifiers aren't sequential, so you can't even use a simple offset (adding a constant value to the row number).

I think that the best solution is not to rely directly on intrinsic types as you are for your dictionary, but rather, create a struct for each sound and store an array of them.  Something like this:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDatasource

   struct Sound {
    var id:Int
    var fileName:String
   }

   var sounds=[Sound]()

   func loadSounds() {
       let soundsDict =
        [1000:"new-mail.caf",
        1001:"mail-sent.caf",
        1002:"Voicemail.caf",
        1003:"ReceivedMessage.caf",
        1004:"SentMessag.caf",
        1005:"alarm.caf",
        1006:"low-power.caf",
        1007:"sms-received1.caf",
        1008:"sms-received2.caf",
        ...
        ]

        for (id,fileName) in soundsDict {
            self.sounds.append(Sound(id: id, fileName: fileName))
        } 
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("soundCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let button = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel //UILabel in "SoundCell"

        button.text=self.sounds[indexPath.row].fileName  

        return cell
    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.sounds.count
    }    
}
```

Comment: i have implement YTPlayerView in tableview cell when i scroll down and after reaching at last point when i scroll up YTPlayerView initialise again.i want YTPlayerView load only once in tableview.do you know anything how to do it?

Comment: You should [ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/wizard)

Comment: thank you for your response but i am unable to do it..because stack overflow says `Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more `.